# How do I create Flutter stream builder?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

I have an "updateDatabase" function that retrieves the data from the Firebase Real-Time Database and saves it in the shared preferences ... I put this function in the Init State of my home page but I would like this to become a stream builder so as not to having to reopen the page each time to get updated data but have them immediately.

This is part of my updateDatabase function:

```
updateDatabase() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  DatabaseReference starCountRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/utenti/$uid/');
  starCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    final data = event.snapshot.value as Map;
    prefs.setInt("videoAgosto2022", data["videoAgosto2022"]);
ect...
}
```

This is part of my home page ...

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double altezza = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

```
  return StreamBuilder(
        stream: What should I put here?,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
```

What should I put in the "dada" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stream function must be marked as `async*`

Then, you just have to put your function in the `stream` attribute of the `StreamBuilder` widget

Comment: thank you very much for the advice and actually it does not give me an error ... but the data is still updated only after reopening the page, not immediately

Comment: Ok I understand. Could you post a more complete sample ? It's actually hard to help you with the sample you posted

Comment: modifying the question and adding lines of code I understood by myself where the problem was ... I updated the shared preferences but did not update the variables connected to them. Thanks anyway you helped me, mark as solved.